# How to lock orientation to Portrait in iOS React Native App?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, orientation

I'm trying to untick the Device Orientation Settings leaving alone Portrait option ticked but it doesn't work. In Android it doesn't rotate but it does in iOS and I don't know why. It rotate in my whole app, no matter which window I am.
Do you know another alternatives to lock the rotate caused by orientation?

[image]

This is my Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>NEXT PORTAL</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>7.7</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>12</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) necesita acceder a su cámara para poder escanear el código QR.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to your microphone (for videos)</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) necesita acceder a la galería para adjuntar fotos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) necesita acceder a la galería para adjuntar fotos.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: In your  Info.plist file from your iOS folder, try removing:
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

Comment: I have no these keys in my Info.plist file :S

Comment: Weird! can you check under ios folder>yourprojectname folder>info.plist

Comment: it will be like `<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>`

Comment: Check my Info.plist, I edited the question.

Comment: Yep...does it worked?

Comment: It still rotating when I orient horizontal the iPhone xD It seems magic!

Comment: I've cleaned the project, rebuilt it, uninstall and install...  I don't know what to do xD

Comment: Weird!  Not sure why its behaving like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. Is not the solution I expected because I thought it would be enough by locking in `XCode` as I mentioned before in the ask but at least it worked.

I installed [`react-native-orientation`](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#readme) and I applied the `Orientation.lockToPortrait()` function on the constructor of `App.js` file and it locked the app to portrait.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Did you already have react-native-orientation before the problem happened?
It can be this library that actually mess-up the locking configuration.

Comment: @Benoit no I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Please perform following steps to lock the orientation to portrait in React Native iOS App:

```
1] Open Your_React_Native_Project -> go to ios -> project_name.xcodeproj file in X-Code.
2] After opening the project in Xcode, select your project name.
3] Now Goto -> General -> Deployment Info and select device orientation as portrait.
4] Execute the "react-native run-ios" command and compile the entire project. Now you can see the effect.
```

Also it has been observed that orientation lock doesn't seem to work on an iPad if "Devices" is set to Universal. If it changed to iPad then it works fine.

Comment: All of these is what I have done and doesn't work. As I said, I unticked all possibilities that wasn't "Portrait" with no changes on the app, it still rotating.

Comment: @Mtg Kha Jeskai, may I know what is the value for "Devices" in Deployment Info?

Comment: @Mtg Kha Jeskai, as I said earlier, it has been observed that orientation lock doesn't seem to work on an iPad/iPhone if "Devices" is set to Universal. Try changing it to iPad or iPhone.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the update. I tried it changing the field from "Universal" to "iPhone" and it still rotating although only "Portrait"  option is marked. T_T

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with you, and it turns out that the reason is because of the configuration of react-native-orientation in my AppDelegate.m

If I uncommented these 2 configs

```
#import "Orientation.h"
```

And

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {return [Orientation getOrientation];}
```

Then it works fine. But these configuration is necessary if you're using react-native-orientation. So I think the final solution is using `Orientation.lockToPortrait()`

Comment: Yep, that worked fine for me. react-native-orientation was blocking xcode configuration.
After removing those lines from my appdelegate.m, locking through xcode worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have total 10 screens, in which 2 screens are in Potrait mode and 8 are in Landscape mode.

**import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';**

So If you want to put some screen in Landscape mode then use

**Orientation.lockToLandscape()**

Or If you want to put some screen in Potrait mode then use

**Orientation.lockToPortrait()**

Answer (score -2):

try to clean the project, rebuild the app, and maybe it helps. once i wasnt able to lock the device orientation and the only way was by ticking the Portrait option.

Comment: I did and I had no changes :(